# Overriding a refinery view, specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, refinerycms

I have a refinery courses engine. It has 3 actions, show, index and classroom.
The routes work fine. For my classroom action, I am rendering a classroom view. Once again the view works fine but the nav and the footer get loaded to as expected. My question is, for this specific view how do I not render the footer or nav.

Answer (score 0):

You should create and use a new layout for that view then. Copy `application.html.erb` to your app from refinery (you can use `rake refinery:override view=layouts/application`). Then rename it to something like `classroom.html.erb` and remove the following section:

```
<footer>
  <%= render "/refinery/footer" -%>
</footer>
```

Then in your courses controller add the following line:

```
layout "classroom", :only => [:classroom]
```

#### Update

The new layout file should be copied to `<course_engine_path>/app/views/layouts/`